# My project is not redirecting me to the specified path of a component with Angular

Tags: angular, web, routes, frontend, angular-cli

good afternoon colleagues, I am initializing my studies with Angular, it created the first component called InicioComponent, however when I start the server the web shows me the content of app.component.html and not the one I have in inception.component. html (I leave image):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZeM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLnzC.png)

I leave the code here where I import the modules:
**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { routing } from "./app.routes";
import { InicioComponent } from "./components/inicio/inicio.component";


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        InicioComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I leave the code here where I do the routing
**app.module.ts:**

```
`import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { routing } from "./app.routes";
import { InicioComponent } from "./components/inicio/inicio.component";


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        InicioComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}`
```

**app.routes.ts:** Here I specify which component each route should go to.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { InicioComponent } from './components/inicio/inicio.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: InicioComponent}

]

export const appRoutingProviders : any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);//aca mandamos todas las rutas
```

I am supposed to be placing this line so that the path goes to the component I want `{path: '', component: InicioComponent}`  but it turns out that it is going to my main component:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2v0C.png)

What could I be missing friends? I am using version 17 of Angular. I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

I tried to add the / in the route, but it didn't work:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '/', component: InicioComponent}

]

export const appRoutingProviders : any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);//here we send all the routes
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove the import for `AppRoutingModule` currently there seems to be two routing modules!

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { routing } from "./app.routes";
import { InicioComponent } from "./components/inicio/inicio.component";


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        InicioComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted that component that actually had nothing. I already removed it from the imports but it still doesn't route correctly to the component I need, do you have another day? ...maybe the problem is here? export const routing: ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

Comment: @HugoBustamante could you provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Comment: I don't know how to use stackblitz :(

Comment: @HugoBustamante copy paste the basic code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9upbsg) and try to replicate the issue